# How Does View::share Work in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have one variable `$kalorija` which i want to share across all views in Laravel.

```
$step1 = round($brmmk)/100;
$kalorija = round($step1)*100;
View::share('kalorija', $kalorija);
```

that variable `$kalorija` i now want to update in my database along with variable `$kile`
but my share do not work at all, can someone please help me?

```
Route::post('/menu/dijeta', function() {

        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $kile = Input::get('kile');
        User::where('id', '=' ,$id)->update(array('kile' => $kile, 'kalorija' => $kalorijax));

        return Redirect::route('dijeta');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`View::share()` is meant for sharing variables across views. You want to access it in a controller/closure.

You could put it in a hidden input in your form that posts to that route.

Or if you want to access it inside your closure you could do something like this: http://laravel.io/forum/06-18-2014-how-to-create-a-variable-accessible-to-all-controllers-and-views?page=1#reply-9165